# Ionic 4 chat application and how to send message to particular user?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, redis, socket.io, lumen

I created application in Ionic 4, and for backend I use Lumen. Application should have chat page and in that purpose I add Redis, Socket.io and nodejs. I successfully created public room, and chat between users in that room works. Problem is how to send private message for user, how to initialize users for their private room.

This is how I created public room:

```
constructor(private socket: Socket) {

        this.getMessages().subscribe(message => {
            this.messages.push(message);
        });

    }

    getMessages() {
        const observable = new Observable(observer => {
            this.socket.on('message', (data) => {
                observer.next(data);
            });
        });
        return observable;
    }
```

I send message from Lumen application and Redis:

```
public function sendMessage()
{
    $redis = Redis::Connection();
    $sendMessage = json_encode(['user' => 'John Doe', 'text' => 'Some message, text', 'channel' => 'message']);
    $redis->publish('add-message', $sendMessage);
}
```

And my node server is:

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let http = require('http').Server(app);
let redis = require('redis');
let client = redis.createClient("redis://127.0.0.1:6379");

let io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use('/', express.static('www'));

http.listen(3000, '192.168.10.10', function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

client.on('message', function(chan, msg) {
    let data = JSON.parse(msg);
    io.sockets.emit(data.channel, msg);
});

client.subscribe('add-message');
```

Bottom line everyone who is subscribed on 'message' channel will get message. Problem is that I subscribe user on channel when came to chat page. I don't know how to subscribe user, and when, on channel where some another user send him message.Also how that sender user to create new room, I suppose to use id of users for room name (per instance user1_user2).

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem? I don't know even I described well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: On Server-side you should save your clients in form of sockets. So any client that connects to your chat application gets an ID, Socket-Object etc. that you just save into a Stack! So Client A ---> send Message to ---> Client B. Try to figure out how you gain access to the socket object. I think socket.io supports rooms etc... For Example: io.on('connection', function(socket){  clients.push({socket, id, room}) } ... So your Server holds an Im-Memory Stack of all clients and their socket (IP/PORT)

Comment: I don't get it, where I should initialize in app user to socket? Because user should be always connected to socket, not only where is on chat page. Also should I create unique ID for room for two users?

Comment: So just for purpose... write io.on('connection', function(socket){//log somthing}) to see all connections/sockets from clients.Try to start out first without redis...

Comment: I can't, I must use Redis

Comment: Maybe I can handle user to user message, but does someone knows how to save chat history with redis, and to know which user is online?

Comment: We're got a chat application using MongoDB and Socket.io but it was a lot of work - more than I can reasonably post as a solution here. Why are Redis and Socket.io a requirement of the project? You can get something reliable going a lot easier using just Firebase messaging.